# Find a name - it not found, then do not write it and its price to the file

Tags: java, arrays, regex, arraylist

Yesterday, I asked a question about finding a string and if it is not found, then do not add write it to the .csv file. I got the answer and the suggested/revised code was working well. However, I added the price to the code and now I am stuck.

```
package sportsCardsTracker;

import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test_Mark6 {
    public static ArrayList<String> listingNameList;
    public static ArrayList<String> pricesList;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        listingNameList = new ArrayList();
        listingNameList.add("LeBron James 2017-18 Hoops Card");
        listingNameList.add("Stephen Curry Auto Patch, HOT INVESTMENTS!");
        listingNameList.add("Michael Jordan 1998 Jersey Worn Card");
        listingNameList.add("Char Barkley NBA Hoops Auto");

        ArrayList<String> playersNamesList = new ArrayList();
        playersNamesList.add("LeBron James");
        playersNamesList.add("Stephen Curry");
        playersNamesList.add("Michael Jordan");
        playersNamesList.add("Charles Barkley");

        pricesList = new ArrayList();
        pricesList.add("$5");
        pricesList.add("$5000");
        pricesList.add("$7000");
        pricesList.add("$500");

        String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File file = new File(directory + "/src/sportsCardsTracker/test.csv");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, false); //true to not over ride 


        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String listingNames : listingNameList) {
            temp = playersNamesList.parallelStream().filter(s -> listingNames.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())).map(s -> s).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
            if(temp.size() > 0){
                System.out.println(temp.get(0));
                //fw.write(String.format("%s, %s\n", temp.get(0));
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

I wanted to do something like, if the code finds the name of a player (spelled correctly) in the `listingNameList`, then write it to the `test.csv` file; if not then do not add it. When I added the price to it, how would I not add the price if I don't find the name of the player's though? How would I know the index to remove the price? I have thought about re-opening (importing) the file again to search again and remove from there, but I feel that it would be very inefficient.

**EDIT:** I actually have thought about creating an ArrayList consisting of the `listingNameList` and `pricesList` too, I believe that that would work better than re-importing the file and re-writing it?

Comment: Do you know about creating your own classes? This seems like a good point to create a class like `CardListing`. You can add the fields `name`, `playerName`, and `price`. Check out the [Objected-Oriented Programming tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/). After creating your own class, you can build an ArrayList containing those objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was my idea #2. Created a new empty ArrayList, say `"temp"` that has both `listingNameList` and `pricesList` (remember to put `pricesList` with `String.valueOf`). From there, I created another ArrayList, that only adds the values from `"temp"` if the name is found. I am still seeking for a better answer for better optimization please. Thank you!